# C program to detect the time change and reset the counter

Tags: c, counter

I have an inbuilt algorithm in my application. Whenever I run the algorithm, it saves that exact run time in the database. For example, if I run the algorithm at 11.00, it saves that time. And again if I run at 11.05, it saves 11.05 in the database.

I want to detect the number of times it Ran. So that once it runs for 5 times, I need to do some action like changing the values and reset the counter to 0.  So that when it reaches 5 iterations, again I should reset the counter.

I am a beginner. It will be helpful if you could help me with the syntax.

```
MAIN
{


 int temp1, temp2, flag = 0, max = 5;

 temp1 = GET_INT_VALUE(8,1,84,1,0);


 if flag = 0;
 while(1)
 {
     if (templ == temp2)
         flag++;
     else
         flag = 0;

     if (flag == max)
     {
        //sprintf(Message,"SE value is %d",temp2);             
        PRINTOUT("Message");
        flag = 0;
        break;
     }

 }
}
END
```

Comment: Well, the first issue is `MAIN {`. That's not valid C syntax.

Comment: Why don't you save the run count too in the same database. That way you could read it at the start of prog, increment it by one and then write that value in database.

Comment: its a wierd combination between C and pseudo code

Comment: It is a combination of C and another inbuilt software

Comment: Insert a counter and when you apply the algorithm just increase it and check if it reaches to 5. if it does, do whatever you want to do like reset it and change the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use a static local variable, like this:

```
void foo(void) {
    static int counter = 0;

    counter++;
    if(counter > 5) {
        counter = 0;

        /* Do something every fifth time */
    }
}
```

Note that you can't use a normal local variable (e.g. `int counter = 0;`) because its contents will be lost when the function returns. The `static` makes it work more like a global variable (so its value isn't lost when the function returns).